# Merge two jQuery Objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

I like to have a return value with one or more jQuery objects to add them to a .

```
var f = function() {
    var a = $('<div class="a" />');
    // do someting awesome
    return a;
};
```

Correct example with two s:

```
var f = function() {
    var ret = $('<div class="a" /><div class="b" />');
    // do something spectecular
    return ret;
};
```

The problem is that I need these two objects separated inside the function and this is not correct code:

```
var f = function() {
    var a = $('<div class="a" />'),
        b = $('<div class="b" />'),
        ret = a+b;
    // do something fabulous
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: why not just do `$('div.a, div.b').each(function() {`. inside the each function, `$(this)` refer to the current jquery object

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the [jQuery `.add()` method](http://api.jquery.com/add/):

```
return a.add(b);
```

From the docs:

> Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the .add() method constructs a new jQuery object from the union of those elements and the ones passed into the method.

Comment: damn shit. thats too easy - i just didn't find this method :)

Comment: @iRaS - Yup, very easy! The jQuery docs is a good place to start... I would recommend you spend an hour or so reading through them.

Comment: you are absolutely right. I read a lot in the documentation. It's the last way to post a question. But I thought it's an object with array structured items so I tried extend() and merge() and read the documentation about read and merge. That doesn't helped me and there is no reference to add()..

Answer (score 0):

I just found a solution for my own question:

```
var f = function() {
    var a = $('<div class="a" />'),
        b = $('<div class="b" />'),
        ret = $.extend({}, a);
    ret.push(b[0]);
    // do something fabulous
    return ret;
}
```

Maybe you have better solutions? It doesn't look very well you know.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

```
var $bindDivs = $.merge( $( '#div1' ), $( '#div2' ) );
```

Comment: Please explain your answer

Comment: @Mazz I really think it's pretty straightforward. I'm just using the jQuery.merge to unificate the two objects in one. I've tested it and it works pretty well. I use it myself.

Comment: Nonetheless you should always explain your answers